# How to iterate many Hive scripts over spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive

I have many hive scripts (somewhat 20-25 scripts), each scripts having multiple queries. I want to run these scripts using spark so that the process can run faster. As map reduce job in hive takes long time to execute from spark it will be much faster. Below is the code I have written but its working for 3-4 files but when given multiple files with multiple queries its getting failed.

Below is the code for the same. Please help me if possible to optimize the same.

```scala
val spark =  SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("my app").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val filename = new java.io.File("/mapr/tmp/validation_script/").listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".hql")).toList

for ( i <- 0 to filename.length - 1)
{
  val filename1 = filename(i)

    scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename1).getLines()
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty)  // filter out empty lines
  .foreach(query =>
      spark.sql(query))


}
```

some of the error I cam getting is like

```
ERROR SparkSubmit: Job aborted.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)

ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 12 (sql at validationtest.scala:67) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1023410176, max: 1029177344)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:528)
```

many different types of error I get when run the same code multiple times.

Below is how one of the HQL file looks like. its name is xyz.hql and has

```sql
drop table pontis_analyst.daydiff_log_sms_distribution
create table pontis_analyst.daydiff_log_sms_distribution as select round(datediff(date_sub(current_date(),cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE ,'u') as int) ),cast(subscriberActivationDate as date))/7,4) as daydiff,subscriberkey as key from  pontis_analytics.prepaidsubscriptionauditlog
drop table pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_distribution
create table pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_distribution as select sum(event_count_ge) as eventsum,subscriber_key from pontis_analytics.factadhprepaidsubscriptionsmsevent where effective_date_ge_prt < date_sub(current_date(),cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE ,'u') as int) - 1 ) and effective_date_ge_prt >=  date_sub(date_sub(current_date(),cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE ,'u') as int) ),84) group by subscriber_key;
drop table pontis_analyst.daydiff_sms_distribution
create table pontis_analyst.daydiff_sms_distribution as select day.daydiff,sms.subscriber_key,sms.eventsum from  pontis_analyst.daydiff_log_sms_distribution day inner join pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_distribution sms on day.key=sms.subscriber_key
drop table pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_final_distribution
create table pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_final_distribution as select spp.subscriberkey as key, case when spp.tenure < 3 then round((lb.eventsum )/dayDiff,4) when spp.tenure >= 3 then round(lb.eventsum/12,4)end as result from pontis_analyst.daydiff_sms_distribution lb inner join pontis_analytics.prepaidsubscriptionsubscriberprofilepanel spp on spp.subscriberkey = lb.subscriber_key
INSERT INTO TABLE pontis_analyst.validatedfinalResult select 'prepaidsubscriptionsubscriberprofilepanel' as fileName, 'average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks' as attributeName, tbl1_1.isEqual as isEqual, tbl1_1.isEqualCount as isEqualCount, tbl1_2.countAll as countAll, (tbl1_1.isEqualCount/tbl1_2.countAll)* 100 as percentage from (select tbl1_0.isEqual as isEqual, count(isEqual) as isEqualCount from (select case when round(aal.result)  = round(srctbl.average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks) then 1 when aal.result is null then 1 when aal.result = 'NULL' and srctbl.average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks = '' then 1 when aal.result = '' and srctbl.average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks = '' then 1 when aal.result is null and srctbl.average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks = '' then 1 when aal.result is null and srctbl.average_weekly_sms_last_12_weeks is null then 1 else 0  end as isEqual from pontis_analytics.prepaidsubscriptionsubscriberprofilepanel srctbl left join  pontis_analyst.weekly_sms_usage_final_distribution aal on srctbl.subscriberkey = aal.key) tbl1_0 group by tbl1_0.isEqual) tbl1_1 inner join (select count(*) as countAll from pontis_analytics.prepaidsubscriptionsubscriberprofilepanel) tbl1_2 on 1=1
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I mean why do you persist and then unpersist and what does those hql files look like?

Comment: I tried and I don't get any error

Comment: all are hql files and are having queries like, I have updated the question with one of the file and what it has

Comment: Your error doesnt actually reflect the problem. Can you try simple queries like `use database` and `show tables` from two different schemas in just two files

Comment: I dont have any idea thought persist will split the memory usage and unpersist will release memory once used.

Comment: yeah, but the issue is how to query all the files (all hqls ), I get this warning message most of the time.   19/10/18 22:50:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 133.0 in stage 64.0 (TID 325438, prd-pldt-EngageAnalytics03.spirnet.ph, executor 1): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(18, prd-pldt-EngageAnalytics21.spirnet.ph, 32905, None), shuffleId=42, mapId=2807, reduceId=133, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1023410176, max: 1029177344)

Comment: If you have `use` and `show table` statements then try something like `scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename1).getLines().filterNot(_.isEmpty).foreach(query => spark.sql(query).show)` inside loop in spark-shell

Comment: I wrote use databases default and show tables in the hql file and ran the spark code got below error ERROR SparkSubmit: 
extraneous input 'default' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 13)

== SQL ==
use database default
-------------^^^   but the same query works fine in Hive console can you help why ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/7338171/piyush-patel

Comment: It should be `use default` and not `use database default`

Comment: yeah got the result +--------+--------------------+-----------+
|database|           tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+--------------------+-----------+
| default|factadhhomesubscr...|      false|
| default|factadhhomesubscr...|      false|
| default|    hbase_subscriber|      false|
| default|           hive_ints|      false|
| default|       hive_part_tbl|      false|
+--------+--------------------+-----------+
https://stackoverflow.com/users/7338171/piyush-patel  now what I need to do or how to proceed further ?

Comment: Further course of action depends on your needs. Read through documentation and find out according to what you want to do. Caching and uncaching is not something you want. So, not sure.

Comment: I already able to run some of the scrpts, if given less scrips as input the job is successful but when it runs with whole 20-25 scripts it gets failed .

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your code is running out of memory as shown below

`failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 1023410176, max: 1029177344)`

Though what you are trying to do is not optimal way of doing things in Spark but I would recommend that you remove the memory serialization as it will not help in anyways. You should cache data only if it is going to be used in multiple transformations. If it is going to be used once there is no reason to put the data in cache.

Comment: I am not doing any cache, and each and every script is different with different logic so not required to be reused, I used unpersist so that memory is released after every execution, can you help me how I can change my code to optimize the spark program https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226630/jjayadeep

Comment: ```persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)``` Is basically caching the dataframe and then you are also using ```toDF()``` which is unnecessary. You can just run sqark.sql(query) and that should solve your problem.

Comment: still facing the same error and help ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226630/jjayadeep

Comment: can you update your question with the latest changes?

Comment: I have updated the question https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226630/jjayadeep